# jQuery fancybox url

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

In my HTML I have the following situation:

```
<a href='product-enquiry.php?product=SR1'>Enquire about SR1</a>
```

This then sends a user through to a separate page where the product ID (in this case SR1) is passed into a input field:

```
<input type='text' value='<?php echo $_GET['product'] ?>'>
```

I would prefer to use fancybox to bring up the product enquiry form in a pop up window. To do this, the JavaScript code for fancybox is:

```
$('.product-enquiry').attr("href", "product-enquiry.php")
```

How do I append a product number to the end of "product-enquiry.php: in the javascript file so that the product number changes depending on which link a user clicks on (For example, if they select the product 'SR2' - how do I pass this through?)

Hope this makes sense and any help would be great.

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: Don't echo values from outside your app directly into the page without encoding them! That's a huge XSS security hole!

Comment: Hi David. Cheers for that - How would I do that?

Comment: $prod = strip_tags($_GET['product']); As this passed param is an ID, which probably has a defined format you should (or could) write a validate_id function to make sure the string is in valid ID-format.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, if I understand your problem correctly you (very probably) just add `$('.product-enquiry').attr("href", "product-enquiry.php?product=SR1");`

If you have several links to products you’ll have to bind click-events.

You’d give your product container (div) an appropriate ID you can then read in the *click()*-called callback function and pass into the href, which you then set for the fancybox.